# Adding object to vector with push_back working fine, but adding objects with accessor syntax [ ] , not working

Tags: c++, performance, vector

I've implemented a merge function for vectors, which basically combines to sorted vectors in a one sorted vector. (yes, it is for a merge sort algorithm). I was trying to make my code faster and avoid overheads, so I decided not to use the push_back method on the vector, but try to use the array syntax instead which has lesser over head. However, something is going terribly wrong, and the output is messed up when i do this. Here's the code:

```
while(size1<left.size() && size2 < right.size()) //left and right are the input vectors
{
             //it1 and it2 are iterators on the two sorted input vectors
    if(*it1 <= *it2)
    {

        final.push_back(*it1); //final is the final vector to output
        //final[count] = *it1; // this does not work for some reason
        it1++;
        size1++;
        //cout<<"count ="<<count<<" size1 ="<<size1<<endl;

    }
    else
    {
        final.push_back(*it2);
        //final[count] = left[size2];
        it2++;
        size2++;
    }
    count++;    
    //cout<<"count ="<<count<<" size1 ="<<size1<<"size2 = "<<size2<<endl;

}
```

It seems to me that the two methods should be functionally equivalent.

PS I have already reserved space for the final vector so that shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: The assertion here might be mistaken, but I don't understand the downvote. Why not explain the error as in Bartek's answer? Is that not consistent with the purpose of SO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can't* add new objects to `vector` using `operator[]`. `.reserve()` doesn't add them neither. You have to either use `.resize()` or `.push_back()`.

Also, you are not avoiding overheads at all; call cost of `operator[]` isn't really much better that `push_back()` one, so until you profile your code thorougly, just use `push_back`. You can *still* use reserve to make sure unneccessary allocations won't be made.

In most of the cases, "optimizations" like this don't really help. If you want to make your code faster, profile it first and look for the hot paths.

Answer (score 3):

There is a huge difference between

```
vector[i] = item;
```

and

```
vector.push_back(item);
```

Differences:

- The first one *modifies* the element at index `i` and `i` must be valid index. That is,

  > 0 <= i < vector.size() must be true

  If `i` is an invalid index, the first one invokes undefined behavior, which means ANYTHING can happen. You could, however, use `at()` which throws exception if `i` is invalid:

  ```
  vector.at(i) = item; //throws exception if i is invalid
  ```
- The second one *adds* an element to the vector at the end, which means the size of the vector increases by *one*.

Since, sematically both of them do different thing, choose the one which you need.